# Is the difference of two concave functions non-convex/non-concave?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a problem:

\begin{align}
\max_{p,q} \log_2(1+ph)\\
s.t: \log_2(1+ph)\leq \log_2(1+qf)\\
p<P\\
q<Q
\end{align}
where $h$ and $f$ are positive real numbers. We can rewrite the problem as:

\begin{align}
\max_{p,q} \log_2(1+ph)\\
s.t: 0\leq \log_2(1+qf)-\log_2(1+ph)\\
0<P-p\\
0<Q-q
\end{align}

is this problem non-convex due to $0\leq \log_2(1+q h)-\log_2(1+p f)$ which is the difference of two concave functions?
Can we say that $\log_2(1+qf)-\log_2(1+ph)$ is a concave function in this case because the constraint requires that $\log_2(1+qf)\geq\log_2(1+ph)$?

I know that we can easily convert the constraint into an affine function by removing $\log_2$ from both sides. But, if we don't do that, is the problem still convex?

The reason I am asking this question is that if we solve the problem by using KKT conditions we mostly get the optimal solution (I am saying "mostly" because I have compared the solution with heuristic search (both the solutions were the same for the values of $f$ and $h$ I have checked), however, it is not feasible to check for all possible values, so I can not be sure if the solution will be always optimal).

Comment: The general answer to "Is the difference of two concave functions non-convex/non-concave?" is no

Answer (score 1):

$(-x^2)-(-x^4)$ is neither convex nor concave.

$(-2x^2)-(-x^2)$ is concave.

$(-x^2)-(-2x^2)$ is convex.

$(-x^2)-(-x^2)$ is both.